# Formatting a string in python with variable number of desired fill parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to implement left padding of variable length of a string with desired fill parameter with the simplest logic if possible, even a pre-built function. e.g: `123` as `dd123` where d is the fill parameter.[`" "` in this case]
As I found out from some sources this can be done via `zfill`.But it pads the string with left zeros.. But I want space padded string.

Again space`" "` padding can be done via `'{:>10}'.format('test')`-Still it is eligible only when the fill amount is hardcoded integer -as `'{:>x}'.format('test')` didn't work `where x is the variable predefined with an integer value`..

So where is the combined solution of those 2 problems?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done easily by following line of code-

```
s.rjust(fill_width,fill_parameter)
```

where s is the string,you can put the VARIABLE no. of bit-places you want your string to occupy in total and put fill-parameter as " "

As example you can see

```
str = "hello world";
print str.rjust(15, " ")
```

this code will result in

```
    hello world
```